# Creating noise maps using ArcGIS for Desktop or Open Source Desktop GIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, open-source-gis, analysis, modelling, noise

In a previous role I helped create [Noise Maps for Northern England](http://services.defra.gov.uk/wps/portal/noise/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hnd0cPE3MfAwMD42BTA093f1Nvk2ATAwNnA6B8JG55A2MCusNB9uHXD5I3wAEcDfT9PPJzU_ULciMMskwcFQHW4PMe/dl3/d3/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/).

The predicted noise levels was done using the [IMMI package](http://www.woelfel.de/en/products/modelling-software/immi-noise-mapping.html) (which I can recommend) and the cartographic output was done in ArcMap.  There are also other packages such as [LimaArc](http://www.softnoise.com/limaarc.htm) which have tighter integration with ArcMap.

[image]

I want to take on a personal project to try and create noise maps for large urban areas in Australia.  I am interested in both mapping noise from traffic (roads, trams, rail), maybe having a stab at aircraft noise and also looking at how the noise from level crossing bells can be heard by surrounding residents.  As its for self development purposes, I have no budget for buying dedicated software like LimaArc or IMMI.

I was wondering **if anyone in the GIS-SE community has found a way to create noise maps in a similar approach to how IMMI/LimaArc does?**

--EDIT--
I had a play with the noise module for OrbisGIS (user16714 answer and comments below), but had some [problems](https://github.com/irstv/noisemap/issues/5) getting it to work - looks like it has a lot of potential but still has to be installed against a beta version and not entirely sure how well it will handle larger datasets. (Will post back if I get further with this).

Ideally I really want to do this all in ArcGIS or a more established open source package (QGIS, GRASS, SAGA, etc.).  Have seen some [papers](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVIII/2-W11/Farcas_Sivertun.pdf) that mention tools to do this in ArcGIS, but can't source any scripts/tools as of yet.

**Has anyone seen any scripts (Python) or free extensions where this can be achieved directly in ArcGIS?**

Comment: Thank you user16714 for forwarding our work. Here some details about how to use it : The source code of the computation core and the tutorial to run it is here :
https://github.com/irstv/noisemap/wiki/Installation A presentation page in French :
http://www.urban-modelling.org/fr/galerie-des-modeles/parcourir-la-galerie/article/noisemap-cartes-de-bruit-avec.html -Nicolas Fortin

Comment: Hi Nicolas and welcome.  Any chance you could have time to put an answer down with some screenshots of typical results.  It mentions a requirement is BD TOPO as an input dataset.  What would I need to do if using a generic DTM?

Comment: And do you have a forum or somewhere I can seek help?  Been playing and already running into problems...

Comment: I'm from Brazil and a member of a research group in Environmental Noise. We're developing a software to predict noise levels wich will work as a plug-in in the ArcGIS package. At this moment we are needing to get real data from noise level meters in octave bands. We also need to have spatialized data including the shapefiles from the area. We can build a great partnership in my opinion if you have interest. Best regards, Angelina.

Comment: when can download LimArc for Arcgis?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Our protocols can take a little getting used to but you have asked a question in the area reserved for Answers so the most likely thing is that it will be deleted or moved to a Comment.  If you are unable to locate LimaArc by googling then perhaps you can ask that as a new Question.

Comment: I think this question needs some editing to turn it into focussed Q&A.  Since both answers relate to OrbisGIS I think it would be best if the question can be re-phrased in a way that they can remain valid answers.  If a different question still needs to be answered then I think that should be asked as a separate focussed question.

Answer (score 3):

The OrbisGIS (http://www.orbisgis.org/) noise map plug-in is a scientific computation core to quickly evaluate the noise impact on European action plans and urban mobility plans.

This model is based on the French standard method NMPB2008. It includes traffic-to-noise sources evaluation and sound propagation processing.

It is currently a 2 dimensional computation core, then the terrain elevation is ignored. It take account of n order reflection, diffraction over vertical walls of buildings. As the quick start tutorial show it, buildings are only a table of polygons.

You can ask for additionnal details on the following forum http://orbisgis.3871844.n2.nabble.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.orbisgis.org/ has a noise map module. Hope can help you

Here one example:  http://orbisgis.3871844.n2.nabble.com/Huge-noise-map-td6775778.html

Here more details:  http://ogrs2012.org/index.php/ogrs2012/ogrs2012/paper/view/77

Here the library: http://github.com/nicolas-f/noisemap#readme

Comment: Thanks for contributing to this site.  Could you add some detail about how you would use this?  Would be a little more helpful than a one line answer.